# How to detect width of TextView that has attribute wrap_content?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout with element TextView

```
<TextView android:textColor="#ffffff" android:text="18 августа"
                    android:id="@+id/program_day1" android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp" android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center" />
```

How can I detect the real size (and margins) of this in the onStart (or other) event? Now it shows "-2" values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views don't get height or width until they are actually drawn on screen.

Try to show the width in the `onSizeChanged` function. Check if a real size will be shown. Use `getwidth`.

Comment: ok, suppose it has already drawn, and on button click I want to get sizes of TextView

Comment: @user826776 see iDroids answer

Comment: i edited the answer plz check .. can some1 tell me if the person who asked is informed if an answer is edited? because i keep adding a comment so that they check my answer

Comment: there is no same event listener in any api. At least I can't find

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int, int, int, int)

Answer (score 1):

try with 
myTextView.getPaint().measureText(myTextViewtext)
it didn't return the size of the view but the size of the text,hope it could help you

Comment: unfortunately i need exactly a size of the view becouse it could be ImageView or other element

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that, you can use `TextView.getWidth()` and `Textview.getHeight()` to get w/h and 
 `LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) TextView.getLayoutParams();` to get margin values

Comment: this isn't helping. Maybe if this element was hardly sized (in dip, pixels), it helps, but in my case element is vaving size android:layout_width="wrap_content"